# How to "synchronize" threads in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, python-3.5

У меня есть 20 "форм" для создания http запроса, и мне нужно пустить их паралельно, и в конце записать их в файл в таком порядке как были созданы потоки.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        httpObj = HttpFunctions()
        httpObj.start_request(self.data, self.name)

    def start_request(self, payload, thread):
        result = self.get_connection(payload) #
        if result == "OK":
            threadLock.acquire()
            info = self.get_info(result)
            threadLock.release()
            print("Thread #" + thread + " is ready!")
            self.save(info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле вариантов даже несколько, но самый правильный, на мой взгляд, - это использовать класс `Event`. При создании потока передаете ему 2 объекта этого класса: `current_thread_finish`, `prev_thread_finish`. Перед тем как записать в файл вызываете: `prev_thread_finish.wait()`, потом запись в файл, потом `current_thread_finish.set()`. Получится что-то такое:

```
prev_thread_finish = threading.Event()
prev_thread_finish.set()
for i in range(4):
    current_thread_finish = threading.Event()
    Worker(4, curr_thread_finish=current_thread_finish, prev_thread_finish=prev_thread_finish).start()
    prev_thread_finish = current_thread_finish
```